# How to web scrape a list using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need help with scraping data from this website using `beautifulsoup` in python can anybody help me with it Please. I ve been juggling between documenation for hrs.

All i need is to store all the names to a single array from these two links
https://angelsname.com/Twin-Boy-Names
https://angelsname.com/Modern-Hindu-Baby-Names/Boy

```
from traceback import print_tb
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml
import time
names=[]
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
for result in soup.select(#MysteryCode)
names.append(result)
print(names)
```

I'm trying different perm and combs but no luck with the mystery code pls guide.

Answer (score 0):

Select your elements and iterate the `ResultSet`:

```
[e.td.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select('table tr:has(td)')]
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://angelsname.com/Twin-Boy-Names'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
[e.td.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select('table tr:has(td)')]
```

---

You may wanna invoke `pandas` this is best practice to scrape table data:

```
pd.read_html('https://angelsname.com/Twin-Boy-Names')[0]['First Name'].to_list()
```

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html('https://angelsname.com/Twin-Boy-Names')[0]
```

or only name list:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html('https://angelsname.com/Twin-Boy-Names')[0]['First Name'].to_list()
```